# Creating multiple unnested records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A controller action invokes the quantity of records to create as

```
@guests = []
@quantity.times do
  @guests << Guest.new
```

which in the form is presented as follows.

```
<%= form_tag multiple_guests_path do %>
  <% @guests.each_with_index do |guest,index| %>
    <%= fields_for 'guests[]', guest do |f| %>
```

the parameters are submitted and look like:

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "guests"=>[{"name"=>"f1", "lastname"=>"l1", [...]}, {"name"=>"f2", "lastname"=>"l2",[...]}], "commit"=>" Send "}
```

However the `multiple` controller action does not process these parameters as guest parameters

```
 params[:guests].each do |guest|
   @guest = Guest.new(guest_params)
```

returning error  `param is missing or the value is empty: guest` for the strong_params setter

```
def guest_params
  params.require(:guest).permit(:name, :lastname,
```

How can this action process the parameters correctly?

Comment: `params.require(:guests)`

Answer (score 1):

When you use `require` on `params` it looks for the key you asked for in the `params` hash and if it can't find it - it raises an error.

In your case:

```
def guest_params
  params.require(:guest).permit(:name, :lastname....
```

you required a key named `guest` and since the params hash you get from the page doesn't have that key you get that error:

`param is missing or the value is empty: guest`

You can see that the passed key is `guests` - in the plural form.

so you should require the correct key:

```
def guest_params
  params.require(:guests).permit( ... )
end
```

I think you can also not require any key, and just use permit:

```
params.permit( ... )
```

**but you should require what you need!**

Comment: Good point: 'require what you need'.  So if some actions require `guest` and others require `guests`, what would the proper syntax be in this case [Yes I realise this is a 2nd question, but it is derived from the first!] ... require, as a verb, seems to apply to a singular subject...  actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb

Comment: Well, you can make 2 different methods `guest_params` and `guests_params` and use each one when you need, or you can use the same method for both but make some condition `if action_name == 'create' .... else ... end` and require what you need in according to the condition for example...